# Can we assign a value inside the if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 0;
    if (x = 0)
      printf("It's zero\n");
    else
      printf("It's not zero\n");
}
```

Why is the statement **`if (x = 0)`** not an error? Can we assign a value like that in an `if` statement? Why is it not generating an error, and why is the `else` statement getting executed?

Comment: You should get a warning from your compiler, and if you don't, turn up the warning level.

Comment: It's allowed, but an extra set of parens should be added to indicate that you really meant to test the result of the assignment.

Comment: Yes, you can assign in a condition, and it's very useful when you need it, and it's a perpetual trap for new C programmers. The result of the assignment, `0`, is compared to see whether it is not equal to 0; it is equal to 0, so the `if` is false and the `else` is executed. Basic C pitfall. And the statement is equivalent to: `if ((x = 0) != 0)` — the extra parentheses explain to the compiler that you intend it.  With a constant zero, that's not sensible; with a variable that might be zero, it makes sense and I prefer the explicit `!= 0` as part of the expression.  `if ((x = 0))` looks silly!

Comment: Expression-oriented programming languages allow more concise code. They don't force you to [separate commands from queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is allowed to assign the value inside the `if` statement. This is very handy, among other things, when you want to call the function and check it's return for error:

```
int rc;
if ((rc = check())) {
    // here rc is non-zero, often an indication of a failure
}
```

Note how I've put an extra pair of parenthesis around my assignment - since it is such an omnipresent source of confusion, compilers are usually warning about assignement in the `if` block, assuming you might have made a typo. Extra pair of parenthesis makes it clear for compiler that this is what I intended.

By the way, there is no special exception crafted here, validity of this syntax stems from general C grammar - an assignment operator evaluates to assigned value.

Comment: Personally, I don't like the double-bracket stutter like that.  I write `if ((rc = check()) != 0)`.  It means the same — but is more explicit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sure, I find it to be a matter of personal preference.

Comment: `int rc = check(); if ( rc != 0 )...` is a **LOT** less bug-prone while also allowing for much more complex error checking.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I do not see this construct as particularly bug-prone. It becomes even more interesting if you want to call this function selectively, based on result of a some other condition (utilizing short-circuit feature). On any rate, YMMV and no one is forcing you to use it.

Comment: @GovindParmar i am C++ guy, an operator is a function to me ))) I think, evaluates is better in C.

Comment: @SergeyA What SO did you get your 43k+ rep points on?!!? ;-)  There probably isn't a day that goes by without four or five questions on problems caused by buggy assignment-in-an-if-statement.  That I see.

Comment: @AndrewHenle hardly an argument. People also tend to return pointers to local variables from functions and pass pointers by value (and expect that to change the value of passed variable) - is it a reason to ban local variables or by-value passing? C is a complicated tool, and it needs to be learned. On any rate, you have your opinions, I have mine.

Comment: @SergeyA *hardly an argument* True.  But then again, "Look at all the raindrops" isn't an argument either.  That would be *evidence* supporting the argument "It's raining".  In this case, it's assignment-in-if-statement that's raining bugs.  Citing another source of bugs isn't a refutation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid syntax, there is no reason to disallow this.

Quoting `C11`,

> [...] An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment. [...]

So, the value which is stored in the LHS operand, would be used for the `if` statement condition evaluation.

In your case, the variable `x` holds the value `0` after the assignment, and `if (0)` is *FALSY*, that's why the `else` block gets executed.

---

However, most of the time, this syntax is used *wrongly*, instead of the comparison. That's why most of the compilers emit a warning message on this construct.

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
>
> ```
>  if (x = 0)
>  ^
> ```

If you're sure what you're doing, you can wrap the `if` condition with an assignment expression in an additional pair of parenthesis, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the only requirement for an `if` statement is that it contains an *expression*. The truth of the statement is based on whether or not the expression evaluates to zero.

The assignment operator also evaluates to the assigned value, so `if(a = 0)` would be false, whereas `if(a = x)` where `x != 0` would be true.

Since the assignment operator is an expression, it is acceptable to place in an `if` statement, though a frequent beginner mistake is to use the assignment operator where they intended to use the equality test operator `==`.

One way you can avoid this is mistake is, if either side of the comparison is an r-value, put that on the left, so that if you ever accidentally use `=` where you meant `==`, you will get a compilation error. Compare:

```
if(p = NULL) // Valid syntax
    ...

if(NULL = p) // Syntax error
    ...
```